# Curious cat in an apartment

Tags: cats, behavior

I live in an apartment in a large city, so I can't let my cat out because he would get lost or run in front of a car. It is a young and very curious cat, so he naturally wants to get out and explore.

He spends a lot of time just sitting in front of a window, staring out, sometimes crying loudly because he can't get out. I bought him a guide, but he doesn't like wearing it (a lot).

What could I do? Is there any way to satisfy the cat's curiosity without letting him out?

Comment: Some streaming video services like Amazon or Netflix have “cat TV” which play soundtracks of birds chirping and videos of fish or squirrels or laser pointers on the screen. A couple of my cats will sit and watch it - it is rather funny. I think it is natural to feel bad for cats sometimes when they want to go explore and we don’t let them. But the bottom line is we can take comfort in the fact that our cats are much safer not running around outside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a lot of things. I am sure that there will be others giving many more options but some of the options that come to mind are as follows -

- Give your cats a lot of toys to play with and keep themselves engaged. For example toy mouse, balls.
- Outdoor cats scratch their claws against objects such as tree bark to prevent overgrowth and keep them at size. So provide some scratching post toys.
- Self groomer and massager toys are available for cats.
- Use laser pointers to play with your cats.
- Use cat teasers like toy bird at the end of a rope to play with your cats.
- Indoor cats many times out of boredom develop eating disorder. They eat a lot and become overweight. Use food puzzle to keep them mentally active and prevent overeating. [Food puzzles for cat](http://foodpuzzlesforcats.com/stationary-puzzles) has excellent guidance about creating food puzzles.
- Buy your cat cat tress. They love to explore and move around the cat trees. Many have hiding places and comfortable resting places too.
- Cats love to eat. Feed them the most tasty cat food available at market (of course taking into consideration appropriate nutrition).
- Cats love to sleep. Give them a lot of comfortable cozy sleeping places.
- Keep some glass windows. Cats love bird watching and it is an excellent time pass for them.
- Always keep the litter box clean. Dirty litter box puts stress on them.

Hope this helps.